# How to store data in Netezza which is encoded in various formats?

Tags: database, encoding, character-encoding, netezza

While storing data in Netezza tables there is a little discrepancy in data. 
For example,'ïžAï»¿ïžAIAI' which is in CP1166 encoding and is being modified when loaded into the table.

How do I avoid this modification of data on load or is there any datatype which supports all types of encoding?

Comment: Are you certain that the data is being modified?  It could be the case that it is simply a display issue.  it would be helpful if you provided the hex representation of the string you are starting with, and then the hex representation of what you think it's being modified to.    Check this question to see how sometimes the two can get confused: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537853/using-nzload-to-load-special-characters/34580455#34580455

Comment: I had gone through this link. But here when I'm inserting records directly into the table, it's being inserted as it is. Incase of loading it using sqlldr(in Oracle) or external table(Netezza) it is getting modified and hex values are changed.

Comment: Can you provide sample values inched of what's going in and coming out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store unicode /Multibyte characters then you have to use NVARCHAR/NCHAR type data type which can store multibyte characters . You can also look at NZCONVERT /Iconv to have the desired output .

Comment: NVARCHAR/NCHAR takes only UTF-8 format, and by using it the data is not being loaded at all and being discarded as bad record.