# Junk characters get imported to netezza warehouse from csv file

Tags: java, csv, encoding, utf-8, netezza

I am trying to import CSV file data into Netezza warehouse,using external table queries through java programming.
I have some lines of data with '- ' and ' (apostrophe) in the text file which we are writing to csv file and importing to Netezza tables programmatically.( I copied these lines from client source file.) After importing this csv file data to Netezza Warehouse through java coding, we found some abnormal characters(like â€“ itâ€™s instead of – it’s) in the table at the place of '-' and ' (apostrophe). So i couldn't guess what is going wrong. Is it the problem with Encoding while writing to csv file ? Please propose solution , i want correct data in db.

Comment: What is the encoding of the CSV file? And show us the Java code that opens and reads that file. Without that information, your question cannot get answered.

Comment: Looks like some kind of Unicode. Try changing the data type of the string columns to Nvarchar at run the program again. BTW: using JAVA to load data may result in slow performance unless you do array inserts. 100000 rows/sec should be your goal

Comment: I can provide sample code.

Comment: csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new BOMInputStream(new FileInputStream(absolutePath.toFile())), Charset.forName("utf-8")), delim.charAt(0),CSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER,CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER);                                                                  while((line1 = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {                                          csvFileWriter.writeNext(line1);..............}

Comment: Can you please provide sample DDL for the target table and for the nzload statement?

Comment: Like Lars, I'd like to see the DDL and sample data.  I have had to wrestle with my own semi-functional umderstandind of codepag conversion issueses.  Perhaps you can learn from some of the lessons I learned recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537853/using-nzload-to-load-special-characters

Comment: CREATE TABLE ADMIN.TEST_1615_1
(ID INTEGER NOT NULL,FULL_NAME NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(255),ISNEW_2 BOOLEAN,AUDIENCE_MEMBER_ID_2 BIGINT)DISTRIBUTE ON (ID);                                                                                         "FULL_NAME" is the targeted column. Sample Data:       "22092","beach – it’s your fantasy"

Comment: For FULL_NAME ,In Table data stored as "beach â itâs".

Comment: @LarsGOlsen ,thanks for the suggestion, i found my DDL query has nvarchar but my nzload query have varchar type mapping, when i made it nvarchar it could able to import the correct format.

Comment: But i want to filter these junk characters programmatically without touching the query part, while reading and writing to file. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't get the last two comments: you are able to load correct data now but don't want to change ...? Is it because somebody else 'dictated' varchar? That MAY be possible but In that case you need to go back to the java program and change it to write all ascii to the file.

Comment: We are instructed not to change the datatype of varcahar in nzload query,  have to fix it in while reading and writing to the csv file. That csv file should be in correct encoding.